# Use StrongLoop to monitor NodeJS application in Linux via proxy

Tags: strongloop

I am trying to monitor StrongLoop test application and get the following error:

```
[root sls-sample-app]# slc strongops
Generating strongops configuration requires a registered email and password.
Visit http://strongloop.com/register if you have not already.

Please enter your: email address: XXX
Please enter your: password: XXX
Error: { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

I have registered on the StrongLoop website and provided the registration details in the above run attempt.
This RHEL 6.3 machine is connected to Internet via proxy. How can the proxy be configured?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

slc strongops doesn't have proxy support as yet, it's being worked on. In the meantime a workaround would be to find your API key from yoru account profile when logged into the dashboard and then create the strongloop.json manually with this info as shown here.

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Setting+up+StrongOps+monitoring#SettingupStrongOpsmonitoring-ConfiguringyourAPIkey

Comment: i have done that already and still no data is available on strongops dashboard

Comment: Yuri,This was more a general workaround. In your case I have sent you a comment requesting more info on your proxy and we can continue to troubleshoot your issue in the ticket. Thanks